# Flutter : Firebase Notifications : in Foreground - Background - Killed on click on the notification

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, push-notification, notifications

I have made a flutter app on Android and used firebase for push notifications .. all things are done perfectly ... I received notification in all cases

my problem is when I click on the notification :
I want to open the data received on Data Set with notification to Pass to specific screen (Called SingleNotification) and Show the content in it.

1. Foreground: nothing happen !!!
2. Background: open the app BUT main Screen
3. Killed or Terminated: Open the app Splash Screen then
   go Single Notification

and display the data correctly.

---

### My Server Send "notificarions", "data" as the Docs of Flutter and Firebase said

Codes:

```
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings("mipmap/ic_launcher");
var ios = new IOSInitializationSettings();
var platform = new InitializationSettings(android, ios);
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(platform);

if (Platform.isIOS) iOS_Permission();

_firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token){

  if(deviceToken == "") {
    _saveFirbaseToken(token);
    print(token);
  }
});

_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on message $message');

    _showNotification(message);

      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SingleNotification(message['notification']['title'],message['notification']['body']),
          ));

  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on Resume $message');

      Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => SingleNotification(message['data']['title'],message['data']['body'])),

  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => SingleNotification(message['data']['title'],message['data']['body']),
        ));
  },
);
```

---

```
_showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> message) async{

var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails('channel_id', "CHANNEL NAME", "Channel Description");
var iOS = new IOSNotificationDetails();
var platform = new NotificationDetails(android, iOS);

// Read Data
String title = message['data']['title'];
String description = message['data']['body'];


await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0,title, description, platform);

Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => SingleNotification(message['data']['title'],message['data']['body']),
    ));
```

}

---

Any help will be appreciated ... Thanks